# Connection Error when connecting to remote website (in PHP) in Android

Tags: php, android, json

I am trying to design a URL Shortener application, which is an extension for my web-app ([Link Here](http://shortit.ml)). The problem is, when I'm trying to connect to my website (using `HttpURLConnection` class) & parse the JSON response, it throws an exception. (I have also designed a mini-api that returns a JSON response when a proper URL is passed)

The Code (which is creating the problem):

```
private String getResponseText(String param) throws IOException
{
    StringBuilder response  = new StringBuilder();
    URL url = new URL("http://<THE-URL>/shorten-api.php?url="+param);
    HttpURLConnection httpconn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpconn.getInputStream()),8192);
    String strLine = null;
    while ((strLine = input.readLine()) != null)
    {
        response.append(strLine);
    }
    input.close();
    return response.toString();
}
```

Reference Used: [My Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991417/how-to-get-response-from-any-url-in-json-for-android-and-than-after-reponse-i-wa)

Comment: What error is thrown? Also what is the value of param when this exception is occurring? First thoughts are to ensure that the param is being encoded properly for URL parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the solution for this : Used HttpGet API (deprecated, but handy).

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
    String line = "";
    try{
        String longUrl = (String) params[0];
        String link = "http://<SHORTENER_URL>/shorten-api.php?url="+longUrl;
        URL url = new URL(link);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(new URI(link));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line);
            break;
        }
        in.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d("SHORT URL",sb.toString());
    return sb.toString();
```

Then, I accessed the extracted string from This :

```
new ShortenAPIConnector(getApplicationContext()).execute(lUrl).get();
```

Thanks for help.